# get rid of certain parts of image with other image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

I don't do photoshop often but right now i'm trying to get the info of an inscryption card, without the background. if this makes sense it's similar to a visual version of audio clipping(when you isolate vocals of a song by taking the song and the instrumental and cancelling the instrumentals out). I have a blank version of the card and the card with the info but need to cancel out the backgrounds. please help.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unless the background images are exactly the same, pixel for pixel, and perfectly aligned then what you want is probably not possible, at least not without considerable manual work. There are better ways to do something like this. If you could share the image, might be able to give you some advice.

Comment: Yeah its called difference keying. Its possible, not much used by graphic designers or photographers because there are methods that suit better the working methods of these industries. But yes its sometimes used in video effects industry, which is closer to audio production in production sensibilities, thus they have better tools for this. It is however the lowest quality keying tool available and requires lot of extra work. So its often the tool of choice when all else has failed. Also lossy compression and difference keying is poison.

Comment: there are many questions here about background removal with Photoshop, use the site search and I'm sure you'll find an answer.

Comment: Thank you all soooo much!

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of do this by placing one over the other, then getting either the Difference or the Exclusion. It depends really on what colours are in each layer.

Original vs. Written on

[image] [image]

Difference vs. Exclusion

[image] [image]

As you can see, one is clean but in the wrong colours, the other has the right colours but would need some further tidying up by hand.